# Change part of the img src based on Page URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to change the img src of a image based on the page URL

For example if I have this img src: https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/223234/assets-diecut/sampleImage/144_a.png

I want to change the 144 number in the src based on the URL of the page.

This is what the URL of the page looks like: **[www.exampleexample.com/request-quote-custom-example-card-printing?notes=Diecut%20model%20number:%20144](http://www.exampleexample.com/request-quote-custom-example-card-printing?notes=Diecut%20model%20number:%20144)**

I want to capture the end of the URL, the **144** part and dynamically add that to the image src.

Is this possible?

Edit: If this isn't possible from the Page URL, would it be easier to get the **144** value from something like this:

```
<input id="testID" class="hs-input" type="text" name="notes" value="Diecut model number: 144" placeholder data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.1:$6.1:$notes.$notes.0" inputmode="text">
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Do you have any existing code (HTML/JS) to share? Have you attempted this yourself yet? The 2 parts to this are to get the `144` from the URL parameter `number` - you should be able to search the web for solutions to this. The second part is basic "string concatenation" (can search for this) to generate the URL, and finally setting the `src` attribute of the `img`. Give these a try first, and then edit your question with more details of where you're stuck.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I wasn't sure where to start. I'm just a beginner. Thank you for your input, I will try researching more and see if I can figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, by js:

1. *Get actual page url*

   **window.location.href;**
2. *Get last part of url*

   **var last_set = window.location.href.split("/").slice(-1);**
3. *Filter non numeric elements*

   **last_set.replace(/\D+/g, '');**

A full example can be this:

```
var last_set = window.location.href.split("/").slice(-1);
var image_number = last_set.replace(/\D+/g, '');
```

Comment: How would I apply this to html?

<img id="myImage" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/234223/assets-diecuts/sampleImages/URL-PARAMETER_a.png">

How would I get the 144 parameter into the src tag where I wrote URL PARAMETER

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm still pretty confused but this is a step in the right direction!